# PHP exec function from text input

Tags: php, html, exec

I am trying to execute a terminal command entered into a text field with php.
I've tried to get it working using bits of code from everywhere. Would really appreciate a little help if you can see where I am going wrong...

```
            <?php
        function doSomething() { 
            echo 'Guess this is working'; 
            exec($command . '2>&1', $output, $return);
            echo "Dir returned $return, and output:\n";
            } 
        if(count($_POST) > 0 && isset($_POST['command'])) \
            { 
            doSomething(); 
            } 
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>

        <html>
        <head>
            <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

            <title>Terminal Emulator</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <form action="%3C?php%20echo%20$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];%20?%3E" method="post">
                <input autocomplete="off" id="command" name="command" type="text">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: This looks insanely dangerous.

Comment: Is this just for your own personal, local use that no-one else will have access to? (please say yes)

Comment: Thats really **BAD** idea!

Comment: You should test if it's working by typing in `rm -rf /` on your linux server

Comment: This is like ripping apart your shirt, exposing your heart and asking to be stabbed.

Comment: It's for my robot, with a raspberry pi brain. basically you can drive around with a video stream. I want to run a google text to speech script from what is typed in the field and play the sound on the pi. any suggestions on a better way?

Comment: In that case, you should predefine functions, instead of allowing any old code to be executed. Edit: Try Google's API.

Comment: I have this script called text2speech.sh on my webserver with

#!/bin/bash
say() { local IFS=+;/usr/bin/mplayer -ao alsa -really-quiet -noconsolecontrols "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=$*"; }
say $*

So I want to run ./text2speech.sh "**text from input field**"

Comment: I'm pretty sure @Horen knew how to program when they got out of their mothers' womb! Give the OP a break and advice not to run commands like that, instead of making fun of their code!

Comment: Thanks, I'm no developer, clearly this is the wrong way to do it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        function doSomething($command) { 
            echo 'Guess this is working'; 
            exec($command . '2>&1', $output, $return);
            echo "Dir returned $return, and output:\n";
            } 
        if(count($_POST) > 0 && isset($_POST['command'])) \
            { 
            doSomething($_POST['command']); 
            } 
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>

        <html>
        <head>
            <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

            <title>Terminal Emulator</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <form action="%3C?php%20echo%20$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];%20?%3E" method="post">
                <input autocomplete="off" id="command" name="command" type="text">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

// where is $output